# How to install Oracle 11g on linux without X?

Tags: linux, oracle, installation

I tried to install Oracle client from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-linx8664soft-100572.html but some genius makes installer working only in X environment. Any idea how to install on server without X'es?

Answer (score 7):

With a [silent mode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24322/app_nonint.htm#BABFFGCE) installation:

> Use silent mode to:
>
> - Complete an unattended installation, which you might schedule using operating system utilities such as cron
> - Complete several similar installations on multiple systems without user interaction
> - Install the software on a system that does not have X Window System software installed on it

I seem to recall you still have to have `$DISPLAY` set, but you don't need an X-Windows client running.

The [client installation guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24322/app_nonint.htm) goes into a lot more detail. (That's the 11gR2 version; [the 12cR1 version is similar](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AXCLI/app_nonint.htm).

Comment: The document http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e10841/app_nonint.htm is no longer available. Regarding Oracle 12, they write: "Oracle Universal Installer requires an X Window System (for example, libx)." Very bad!

Comment: @HolgerJakobs - thanks, links updated. The [12c silent mode notes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AXCLI/app_nonint.htm#BABFFGCE) are the same as 11g but I've linked to both versions of that doc. I don't know if you need libx on a [Linux](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CWLIN/prelinux.htm#CHDDJBJF) server to install 12c - it may have a lib dependency? - but you can still run it silently.

Comment: [12cR2 version of the documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/rilin/reasons-for-using-silent-mode-or-response-file-mode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you might run 12c+ dbca from the command line.  The parameters are all pretty much self-explanatory

```
dbca -silent -createDatabase  -templateName General_Purpose.dbc  -gdbname MY_CDB -sid MY_CDB -responseFile NO_VALUE \
 -characterSet AL32UTF8  -sysPassword MyPassword123  -systemPassword MyPassword123  -createAsContainerDatabase true \
 -numberOfPDBs 1 -pdbName MY_PDB -pdbAdminPassword MyPassword123 -databaseType MULTIPURPOSE \
 -automaticMemoryManagement false -totalMemory 2000 -storageType FS  -datafileDestination "//oradata/" \
 -redoLogFileSize 200 -emConfiguration NONE -ignorePreReqs
```