# SSH Xforwarding changing user accounts

Tags: oracle, ssh, rhel, xserver

I am trying to make a script to install more or less automatically oracle database as well as some other application of my own. I haven't writen a line yet because I want to make all steps manually first.

So, my environment is the following. I have RHEL 5 with no graphic interface. I am connecting to the server from Windows laptop through SSH as root. I have enabled XForwarding, so when I login with root account I can run xdpyinfo so that I can check XServer configuration.

I need XForwarding because the Oracle DB installation procedure requires an XServer. However, Oracle requires the user oracle to perform the installation. I have already created the oracle user but when changing the user from root to oracle I can no longer run xdpyinfo command so the Oracle installation procedure fails. I get the following error:

```
Xlib: connection to "localhost:10.0" refused by server
Xlib: PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted
xdpyinfo:  unable to open display "localhost:10.0".
```

I have tried to use xhost to enable my laptop to access my server but I have failed as well to do that.

Comment: [A silent install with a response file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16566546/266304) would probably make more sense if you want to automate this, and would make this unnecessary. Why aren't you just ssh'ing in as the Oracle user though?

Comment: Because oracle user should not exist before installing the application, I would create the user with my script and then change from root to oracle and start the Oracle installation. I'll have a look to the silent install with response file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really feel the need to do this, then while you are root, get the current `$DISPLAY` value, particularly the first value after the colon, which is `10` in your case. Then find the current X authorisation token for your session:

```
xauth list | grep ":10 "
```

Which will give you something like:

```
hostname/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  2b3e51af01827d448acd733bcbcaebd6
```

After you `su` to the `oracle` account, `$DISPLAY` is probably still set but if not then set it to match your underlying session. Then add the `xauth` token to your current session:

```
xauth add hostname/unix:10 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 2b3e51af01827d448acd733bcbcaebd6
```

When you've finished you can clean up with:

```
xauth remove hostname/unix:10
```

That's assuming PuTTY is configured to use `MIT-Magic-Cookie-1` as the remote X11 authentication protocol, in the Connection->SSH->X11 section. If that is set to `MDM-Authorization-1` then the value you get and set with `xauth` will have `XDM-AUTHORIZATION-1` instead.

It might be simpler to disconnect from `root` and start a new `ssh` session as `oracle` to continue the installation, which would also make sure you don't accidentally do anything unexpected as `root`. Well, until you have to run `root.sh`, anyway.

If you do a [silent install with a response file then you don't need a working X11 connection anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16566546/266304); you just need `$DISPLAY` to be set, but nothing is ever actually opened on that display so it doesn't matter if `xdpyinfo` or any other X11 command would fail. I'm not sure how you're thinking of scripting the X11 session, but even if that is possible a silent install will be simpler and more repeatable.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to go for the silent install option instead.